# VB6 How to get the SQL Sum result to textbox

Tags: mysql, vb6

How can I get the result of my SQL sum query into a TextBox? Here is my code:
I need to get the SQL sum result to `Text112`.

```
If rs3.State <> 0 Then rs3.Close
    rs3.Open "select sum(TotalHours) as thrs from tbldwardetails where employeesid  =" & Val(empids) & " And dwardate=" & Val(dwardate), db, 3, 3
    If rs3.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        Text112.Text = rs3!thrs
    Else

    End If
```

Comment: You are actually doing the right thing IMO unless your sum is always 0 and you are not passing it to the right textbox control. although I would choose EOF and BOF for testing the result of the query and if you are not doing anything in the recordset I also recommend to immediately close it and use the Field instead of ! when retrieving values for performance issue.

Comment: I suspect you are doing the *wrong thing.*  This should return a Null result when no rows match the selection criteria, i.e. the result *always* has one row of one column but it may contain Null.  RecordCount, BOF, EOF are all silly things to be looking at.  The function returns Null in order to distinguish it from a Sum that totals to 0.  Some fools will coerce Null to 0 in the SQL expression but it always makes more sense to test the result in code because Null is not 0 and has a specific meaning, in this case "nothing matched."

Comment: It could be null indeed since he is using SUM. I forgot that SUM is different from COUNT when no rows has been found in the criteria. He could probably receiving an invalid use of NULL error in passing the value to a textbox control, but did not mention. And yes testing the result for EOF and BOF won't make any sense since SUM or COUNT would always return a row. Up voted.

Answer (score 0):

Take note that `Sum()` *return always 1 record*, but the returned value maybe Null if no record satisfies the condition.

So you have to check only if the returned value is null or not:

```
If not IsNull(rs3!thrs) Then
    Text112.Text = rs3!thrs
Else
    Text112.Text = "0" ' or vbNullString
End If
```

N.B. RecordCount should not be used because it value is depend from Cursor side:

- Server side (adUseServer) is default and return always -1
- Client side (adUseClient) return the record count

Answer (score 0):

You can use a smarter query to return a value if the result is null.

```
If rs3.State <> 0 Then rs3.Close

rs3.Open "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(TotalHours), 0) as thrs from tbldwardetails where employeesid  =" & Val(empids) & " And dwardate=" & Val(dwardate), db, 3, 3

If rs3.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    Text112.Text = rs3!thrs
Else
    '?
End If
```

In the query above the IFNULL function will return 0 if the SUM function returns NULL.

Sorry, I just noticed the MySQL tag. I have never used MySQL, but the W3C documentation shows the IFNULL function and it looks like it is used the same way.

W3Schools documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp